# Creating an array from query?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a proper way to do this:

```
$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryResult)){
    $queryArray[$i] = $row['instructionValue'];
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace

`$queryArray[$i] = $row['instructionValue'];`

with

`$queryArray[] = $row['instructionValue'];`

and get rid of the `$i` variable.

When you assign a value to an array this way (with braces, but no index) you automatically create a new item at the end of array and assign the value to it.

Comment: Works like a charm! I really didn't know that it work that way...  am embarrassed!

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in functionality to do this with mySQL, but it is trivial if you move to using the PDO abstraction layer (which I would strongly advise you to do -- it's brilliant).

For instance:

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name FROM user');
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

`$result` is now an array containing all the rows found in the query.

Comment: Agreed.   Once you get the hang of PDO, it's wonderful to work with.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResult)){
    $queryArray[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}
```

Changing `$row['instructionValue'];` to just `$row` You will get an `$array` with all records.

in the while i used mysql_fetch_assoc.

Note you can get rid of the `$i` by doing just `$queryArray[]=$row;`